# How to use listen to event only for mouse left click?

Tags: javascript, typescript, html5-canvas, phaser-framework

Phaser by default treats all mouse clicks (middle and right, too) as a click event. I want to do execute a function only when mouse left is clicked, not on right/middle click. Is there any way to do it?

In the following link is a Phaser example, where right/middle click is also execute: [https://phaser.io/examples/v2/basics/02-click-on-an-image.](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/basics/02-click-on-an-image)

Comment: Please add the shortest code necessary to reproduce

Comment: Yes, there are multiple ways you could approach this problem. You should pick one and come back if you have problems implementing it

Comment: That's how browsers work, is not framework specific The event object will tell you which button was clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
game.input.activePointer.leftButton.isDown
```

https://phaser.io/examples/v2/input/mouse-buttons

Comment: This is outdated

Answer (score 1):

suggestion :

Bind a function on the mouseup event of the Element you want and evaluate the "button" property of the event.  The value of this field will indicate if it is a left or right click

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
click me :
<a id="test" href="#">Try it</a>

<script>
$("#test").on("mouseup", function(e) { myFunction(e);});



function myFunction(e) {
  
  if(e.button === 0)
    alert('left click');

if(e.button === 2)
    alert('right click');
  
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div onmousedown="WhichButton(event)">Click this text with one of your mouse buttons to return a number.
  <p>
  0 = The left mouse button<br>
  1 = The middle mouse button<br>
  2 = The right mouse button
  </p>

</div>

<script>
function WhichButton(event) {
  alert("You pressed button: " + event.button)
}
</script>
```

Here 0 indicates left click so you can write condition like this :

```
function WhichButton(event) {
      if(event.button==0) {
         alert('left click');
      }
}
```

Hope this help.